# Outlook Add-in - Error while switching emails in pinned mode

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an `Outlook Add-in` TypeScript Angular add-in. I deployed my add-in to Azure and it worked fine. I'm getting the error ([screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRV43.png)) while `swapping between emails and folders`(Inbox/sent items, etc..) in `Pinned mode`.  It is working fine in normal mode facing issue only when enabled pinned mode and swapping different mails.

Environment: `Outlook on Windows`

piece of `Manifest` code:

```
               <OfficeTab id="messageReadTab">
                    <Group id="messageReadTab.mainGroup">
                       <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                       <Control xsi:type="Button" id="openSidebarReadButton">
                        <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                        <Supertip>
                          <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                          <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                        </Supertip>
                        <Icon>
                          <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                          <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                          <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                        </Icon>
                        <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                          <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                          <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
                        </Action>
                       </Control>
                    </Group>
                  </OfficeTab>
```

Below is my `code snippet:`

```
Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync(
      Office.EventType.ItemChanged,
      function (eventArgs) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          window.location.reload();
          _this.homeDetails = new Array<any>();
          _this.getNewMailToCcRecepEdit();
          _this.loadIninailCalls();
        }, 500);
      },
      function (asyncResult) {
        // window.location.reload();
      }
```

Error: I'm facing this error stating: *Sorry, we can't load the add-in. Please make sure you have network and/or Internet connectivity. Click "Retry" once you're back online*

I even tried to re-install `Dev certificates` in my local machine as mentioned [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office/blob/master/src/docs/ssl.md#windows) to resolve this but no luck.
Can anyone please guide me on this?

If required, I can share part of my manifest file.

Comment: Hey, which platform are you facing this issue in (Outlook for Windows, Outlook for Web, or Outlook for Mac)? Or is this a common issue across clients?

Comment: Outlook for Windows

Comment: What is your code in the `ItemChanged` event handler? Do you see that right after task pane start or after selecting items in Outlook?

Comment: @Eugene Astafiev I have updated my code snippet please check

Answer (score 0):

Don't use window.location.reload. One of the benefits of using pinnable pane is to send you an event, so that you don't have to reload all your HTML/JS again. It is likely the reload is causing the issue.

If this is not the issue, it is likely something else in your event handler code that is causing it. You could try systematically removing/adding code in the event handler, to see what may be the culprit.

Comment: I figured out issue. I have removed window.location.reload(); in setTimeout and put out side then it working fine. Thanks for your response.